# Variable 'aged'... when crossing data from php to socket.io (nodejs)

Tags: php, node.js

I have the following function in PHP

```
function something($counter){
     return time() + $counter;
}
```

`something(0)` gives me the time, e.g, 1441419525.

Here is the complete flow:

```
$var = something(0);
array_push($some_array,$var);
$var2 = $some_array;

//$var2 goes into $_SESSION

//nodejs makes a visit and steals $_SESSION
console.log(session)
```

Now here is the freaky stuff:

```
#=> everything correct except the value for $var1: 144141952'6' <--
```

I'm assuming +1 because the transaction is fast atm. And I think the function in PHP is being called again in any way I'm not understanding.

What exactly could be wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me the setup to connect PHP with Node.js, please? About your question: How do you get `$var1`? Is that called up to a second later? Or you are calling `something()` a microsecond before that, but switching to another second? So how do you get the variable?

Comment: Just as I wrote. $var is called then pushed to the array. Nothing more, nothing less. I'm using simple CURLs to talk between the plats.

Comment: Ah, awesome, thanks. So about your question, can you post a line of `$var1, $var2, ...` outputs here? Is this the same amount in all of them?